# Update an exisiting Map Object when using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Here I am converting two different list to a single map. Before I used normal for loop to do this. Now I am using streams due to performance issues. How can I use a same mapObject for both the list of objects when using streams.

```
final Set<Object1> objects1 = new HashSet<Object1>();
final Set<Object2> objects2 = new HashSet<Object2>();
final Map<Id, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<Id, Object>();


private void addObjectsToMap(Map<Id, Object> objectMap, final Collection<? extends Object> objects)
{
    // used this operation earlier to convert
    for (final Object object : objects)
    {
        objectMap.put(object.getId(), object);
    }

    // using this one now
    objectMap = objects.parallelStream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(object -> object.getId(), object -> object));
} 

addObjectsToMap(objectMap, objects1);
addObjectsToMap(objectMap, objects2);
```

Comment: You had a *performance problem* with a normal loop? How many objects do you have?

Comment: It varies from thousand to million objects

Comment: Accept varargs in your method and use flatMap to transform both collections into one stream should work

Comment: What you have now is you are creating entirely different map, you do not collect into the one you had passed inside the method. Also, using parallel stream will not aid with performance - you will just spread the load between more workers and introduce parallelization overheads.

Comment: Is there some magic involved that makes `Object` having a `getId()` method?

Comment: @Holger Both sets have elements which typed in order Object1 and Object2. But i didn't understand  this > new HashSet<Object>()  i believe this one is typo. it needs to be HashSet<Object1> (or Object2).

Comment: @Ömer Erden: or just `new HashSet<>()`. But I was referring to the method which receives a `Collection<? extends Object>`, but I suppose, “`Object`” is meant as a not-so-well-chosen placeholder for “common base type of `Object1` and `Object2`”.

Answer (score 3):

You can concat 2 stream into single stream with Stream's [concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-)

```
Map<Integer, Object> objectMap;
objectMap = Stream.concat(objects1.stream(), objects2.stream())
                  .parallel()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::getId, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: Or `Stream.of(objects1, objects2).flatMap(List::stream)`